# Angular Translate default translate value while using filter

Tags: angular-translate

Is there any way to provide the translate-default value while using the filter instead of directive?

e.g:

How to achieve the same results as this

`<h3 translate="TEST" translate-default="Not present"></h3>`

with filter format

#### {{ 'TEST' | translate }}

How do i put the "translate-default" attribute when using the translate filter?

What i need to do is show the original text if the key is not present.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a wrapping filter for that purpose:

```
.filter('txf', ['$translate', ($translate: angular.translate.ITranslateService) => {
    return (input: string, stringIfNotAvailable: string = '') => {
        const translation = $translate.instant(input);
        return translation === input ? stringIfNotAvailable : translation;
    };
}]);
```