# Does angularjs translate support providing a default text in markup?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have an old angularjs app and need some text translated where the language key *might* or *might not* have existing translation so I need to provide a default text to show. I am using the `translate` directive.

I have tried this variant that I found example of [another place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40611501/109392), but this does not work.

```
<span translate="connectionPointType_{{typeCode}}" translate-default="{{typeCode}}"></span>
```

I need this to show the value of `typeCode` if the corresponding language key does not exist.

Example:
`$scope.typeCode = 'XYZ'`
In this case the language key will be `connectionPointType_XYZ`. But this does not exist as a language entry, so I want the text `XYZ` to be shown. Currently, the translate service returns just the key as default, which in this case is `connectionPointType_XYZ`.

So my question is: does the old angularjs version support something like this?